# Check if logged in

Tags: php

Hi everyone,

Im trying to figure out why my script keeps redirecting to my login page. So far I haven't found it yet. Could someone explane to me which mistakes I'm making?
This is my code.

**functions.php**

```
function redirect_to($location = NULL) {
    if ($location != NULL) {
        header("Location: {$location}");
        exit;
    }
}

function include_layout_template($template="") {
    include(SITE_ROOT.DS.'public'.DS.'layouts'.DS.$template);
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

require_once('../../includes/initialize.php'); ?>
<?php if (!$session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to("login.php"); } ?>

<?php  include_layout_template("admin_header.php"); ?>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>


<?php  include_layout_template("admin_footer.php"); ?>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php


class Session {

    public $logged_in = false;
    public $user_id;
    public $message;

    function __construct() {
        session_start();
        $this->check_message();
        $this->check_login();
        if($this->logged_in) {
            // actions to take right away if user is logged in
        } else {
            // actions to take right away if user is not logged in
        }
    }

    public function login_user($user) {
        if($user) {
            $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
            $this->logged_in = true;
        }
    }

    public function is_logged_in() {
        return $this->logged_in;
    }

    public function logout() {
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($this->user_id);
        $this->logged_in = false;
    }

    private function check_login() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $this->logged_in = true;
        } else {
            unset($this->user_id);
            $this->logged_in = false;
        }
    }
    private function check_message() {
        // Is there a message stored in the session?
        if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
            // Add it as an attribute and erase the stored version
            $this->message = $_SESSION['message'];
            unset($_SESSION['message']);
        } else {
            $this->message = "";
        }
    }
}

$session = new Session();
//$message = $session->message();
```

**user.php**

```
<?php

require_once('../../includes/initialize.php');

class Users extends DatabaseQuery
{

    protected $tablename = 'users';
    protected $db_fields = array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'username');
    public $id;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $password;
    public $username;

    public static function create_user($first_name, $last_name, $password, $username)
    {
        global $database;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (";
        $sql .= "first_name, last_name, password, username) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES (";
        $sql .= "'{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$password}', '{$username}')";
        $result = $database->query($sql);
        return $result;

    }

    public static function find_username($username) {
        global $database;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ";
        $sql .= "WHERE username= '{$username}' ";
        $sql .= "LIMIT 1";
        $result = $database->query($sql);
        $admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $admin;
    }


    public static function find_password($username, $password) {
        global $database;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ";
        $sql .= "WHERE username= '{$username}' ";
        $sql .= "And password=".crypt($password) ;
        $sql .= " LIMIT 1";
        $result = $database->query($sql);
        $admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $admin;
    }

    public static function password_check($password, $existing_hash) {

        $hash = crypt($password, $existing_hash);
        if ($hash === $existing_hash) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static function login($username, $password) {
        $admin = self::find_username($username);
        if ($admin) {
            // found username, check password.
            if (self::password_check($password, $admin['password'])) {
                //password matches
                return $admin;
            } else {
                //password does not match
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // admin not found
            return false;
        }
    }

}

$user = new Users();
```

**login.php**

```
<?php


/**
 * FIRSTNAME        LASTNAME        PASSWORD        USERNAME
 * Coos             Wolff           secret          Admin
 * Kevin            Doofus          password        Kevin
 */

include_once("../../includes/initialize.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

    $login = Users::login($username, $password);

    if($login) {
        $session->logged_in = true;
        redirect_to('index.php');
    } else {
        redirect_to('login.php');
    }

} ?>

<form id='login' action='create_user.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <fieldset >
        <legend>Create User</legend>
        <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

        <label for='username' >UserName:</label>
        <input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />

        <label for='password' >Password:</label>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />

        <label for='firstName' >FirstName:</label>
        <input type='text' name='first_name' id='first_name'  maxlength="50"  />

        <label for='lastName' >LastName:</label>
        <input type='text' name='last_name' id='last_name'  maxlength="50" />

        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
    </fieldset>
</form>

<hr /><br /><hr />

<form id='login' action='login.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <fieldset >
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

        <label for='username' >UserName:</label>
        <input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" VALUE="Kevin"/>

        <label for='password' >Password:</label>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />

        <label for='firstName' >FirstName:</label>
        <input type='text' name='first_name' id='first_name'  maxlength="50" value="Kevin" />

        <label for='lastName' >LastName:</label>
        <input type='text' name='last_name' id='last_name'  maxlength="50" value="Doofus"/>


        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

If I submit the form without the code to check if somebody is logged in the code works fine. But with the checking code it keeps redirecting me to the login page. After submitting the form I set $session->logged_in = true. But still nothing. I have look on google to see what im doing wrong. But I can't figure it out. I tried many different codes but it all ends up the same way. Redirecting me to the login in page. It's probably an easy fix. But I just can't see it. Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Kind Regards,
Coos

Answer (score 0):

You are going to laugh when I tell you this. According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php):

> If the return is omitted the value NULL will be returned.

```
public function is_logged_in() {
    // Add the return statement
    return $this->logged_in;
}
```

It is returning NULL, which is a "falsy" value so your check thinks it's not logged in.

Comment: If this answer has solved your issue, please consider accepting it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/311727

Comment: that was really stupid to forget. Sadly it didn't work though.

Comment: Try to do a `var_dump()` of the result of `is_logged_in()` at various points to debug where it is going wrong then.

Comment: if I put var_dump() on top of my login.php page it returns bool(false). It does the same on my index .php page. Can't figure out why. Cause I set it to true on the login.php page if the form is submitted.

Comment: Make sure you are putting it somewhere after `session_start()` has been called and also make sure you are passing it the value to dump like `var_dump($session->is_logged_in());`

Comment: I will. Thanks for you time. I really appreciate it. I will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: I think I'm loosing my mind :) It keeps returning false. Whatever I do. I feel really stupid at the moment :)

Comment: FInally I found it. $_SESSION['user_id'] wasn't set and returned NULL. I found it out with var_dump(). Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: I had faith in you! Learning to debug is the most important lesson a developer will ever learn.

Comment: I noticed that. After that moment I realized I finally understand whats happening :) Only started 4 months ago. So really new to all of it.